# Why can't I use nested IntList to create an object?

Tags: java, instantiation

Why can't I create an instance by using nested IntList just like I do in Python?

I got Error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method IntList(int,)
location: class IntList

```py
class Link:

    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

s = Link(3, Link(4, Link(5)))
```

```java
public class IntList {
    public int first;
    public IntList rest;

    public IntList(int f, IntList r) {
        first = f;
        rest = r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntList L = new IntList(15, IntList(10, null));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `new` to your second `IntList` instance:

```
IntList L = new IntList(15, new IntList(10, null));
                            ^^^
```

Without this, it's trying to find a method named `IntList`.